# A dynamic column name with value in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, left-join

I'm trying to execute a SQL query which will return a custom column with a default value.

This is the actual query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME 
FROM dbo.A 
WHERE (A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.ID FROM dbo.B)) AND (A.ID = 5)
```

But I would like to return the result as follows-

```
ID  |   Name   |   Address
===============================
1   |  abc     |  Not available
2   |  xyz     |  Not available
```

Please note that, `Address` column is not in the database table.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this. Should work

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, 'Not available' as Address
FROM dbo.A 
WHERE (A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.ID FROM dbo.B)) AND (A.ID=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Not available` as column and Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `IN` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, 'Not available' AS Address
FROM dbo.A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL AND A.ID=5
```